# Why is dhclient making DHCP requests on a static interface?

Tags: debian, networking

I'm setting up a new Debian system.  I have a static IP configured on an interface in /etc/networks/interfaces like so:

```
# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# The primary network interface
allow-hotplug eth4
iface eth4 inet static
        address <redacted>
        netmask 255.255.254.0
        network <redacted>
        broadcast <redacted>
        gateway <redacted>
        dns-nameservers <redacted>
        dns-search <redacted>
```

I've hidden the addresses, but the configuration matches an older Debian system except the IP address of course.  I can bring it up with 'ifup eth4' and it works fine for a while but eventually crashes somewhere between 1 and 24 hours later.  I don't see any information in the logs concerning why it goes down.  I'm able to bring it up the next day from the physical console... running 'ifdown eth4' reports that it isn't up to begin with.  Running 'ifup eth4' brings it up without issue.

While I'd like to get *that* sorted out, I've noticed while looking for errors concerning eth4 that dhclient is running in the background making DHCPREQUESTs on eth4 every 2 minutes.  It's happening even right now while eth4 is running properly with the static IP configured.  What's that about and might it be causing the interface to go down?  It seems like I ought to stop dhclient from doing this unnecessarily regardless of whether it's causing the trouble or not.  The older system doesn't have a 'dhclient' process running.

Sorry if this is basic stuff, there are some holes in my Linux knowledge.

Comment: You will get this behavior if `dhclient` was already running when you changed it to a static configuration. Just kill `dhclient`.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense.  I went ahead and just rebooted and it is indeed gone.  Was this also the likely cause of the interface going down or is that another issue?

Comment: `... eventually crashes ...`: what does this mean? A kernel panic? Or just that the interface is down?

Comment: It doesn't leave a trace in the logs, so probably not a kernel issue.  At some point the network interface simply goes down.  However, it is no longer occurring since I've rebooted to stop the dhclient process, so presumably that was doing something to cause the interface to go down.  Lesson learned... reboot after a major networking change if you don't know enough about the nuts and bolts to avoid doing it.

Answer (score 6):

`dhclient` process does not stop when you change `/etc/network/interfaces` file from `dhcp` to `static` type. see https://askubuntu.com/questions/459140/why-dhclient-is-still-running-when-i-choose-static-ip for more info

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem, And finally I found out that it was due to the `ConnMan` service. Indeed, `ConnMan` configure the interfaces `Automatically` for us.

So stop the service

```
sudo /etc/init.d/connman stop
```